# Add element to the beginning of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JS array so:

```
var car_type_1 = [12,16,23,31,33,34,39,45,49,54,59,62,62,62,63,63,64,66,69,71,73,75,78,80,82,85,87,89,91,94,95];
var car_type_2 = [17,20,28,35,37,38, and so on];
```

I created another array which stores the subtracted values between the consecutive numbers in the old array:

```
    function diff(arr) {
      return arr.slice(1).map(function(n, i) { return n - arr[i]; });
    }

var car_type_1_diff = diff(car_type_1);
//so on
```

Understandly, the new array has 1 less element compared to the old array. What I want to do is add the first number of the old array to the new array, so it should be like:

```
  car_type_1_diff = [**12**, 4, 7, 8, 2, 1, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1]
```

12 should be pushed to the beginning of the new array 1. How can I do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Comment: Others have answered this below with words. I'm dropping in a link to devdocs.io here as it's infinitely more useful than the MDN link provided: https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/unshift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift?v=control) method.

Example from the referenced docs:

```
var arr = [1, 2];
arr.unshift(0); // result of call is 3, the new array length
// arr is [0, 1, 2]

arr.unshift(-2, -1); // = 5
// arr is [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]

arr.unshift([-3]);
// arr is [[-3], -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Note that `unshift` returns an integer and mutates the array, a behavior which may be undesirable if you're shooting for immutable state.

Answer (score 3):

In ES6, when constructing the new array car_type_1_diff you can also use the [spread operator](http://devdocs.io/javascript/operators/spread_operator) like so: `var car_type_1_diff = [12, ...diff(car_type_1)]`

Comment: This is the preferred approach when compared to `unshift` when array mutation is not desirable and helps build more predictable applications.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are looking for [unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) method.

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example usage of `unshift` in the answer.